# Is this answer OK as regards "referencing material written by others?"

Tags: discussion

Is this [Geremia's answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/36527/what-is-the-catholic-interpretation-of-john-1926-27/36563#36563) to [What is the Catholic interpretation of John 19:26-27?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/36527/what-is-the-catholic-interpretation-of-john-1926-27) OK as regards ["referencing material written by others?"](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/referencing)

If yes, in what way?

---

**Note:** Please see the comments exchange below the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.  It's not OK.

From the [help center](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/referencing):

> Do not copy the complete text of external sources; instead, use their
>   words and ideas to support your own. And always give proper credit to
>   the author and site where you found the text, including a direct link
>   to it.

In that answer, there was no "his own" answer, it was simply text copied from other sources.

If you flag items like that, be sure to keep it simple:  Flag it and just put "This is plagiarized from another source with not original work from the answerer" or something like that.